# How to pass arguments to karate feature file from selenium java test file

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, junit5, karate

I want to pass an argument to karate graphql test from selenium java test.
I tried to do that this way, but it didn't work.

```
HashMap<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("argument1", "value1");
Map<String, Object> result = CucumberRunner.runFeature(featureFile, 
args, true);
```

I tried to put that value in karate file in ways like

```
<argument1>
```

or

```
#(argument1)
```

but literally this text was passed to query in karate test. Have someone done that by karate?

Here you have fragment of my feature file:

```
Given text query =
"""
{
  element(name:"<argument1>") {
    name
  }
}
"""
And request {query: '#(query)'}
When method post
Then status 200
* print response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed a [`replace`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace), try this:

```
Given text query =
"""
{
  element(name:"<argument1>") {
    name
  }
}
"""
And replace query.argument1 = argument1
And request {query: '#(query)'}
When method post
Then status 200
```